# ruby write value from sql table to a tmp folder

Tags: ruby

I have this code

```
    #check if haus table is not blank   
      if !haus.blank?
             temp = Dir.mkdir("C:/thistemporary/")
         puts "tempfolder is created"
                haus.each do |file|
                dataname = file.name
                datavalue = file.data
            end
       end
```

I need to iterate through the haus table, that has "data column" (longblob) and "name column"(varchar), save  each data with its name and value related inside the temp folder. How can I do this?

Thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if !haus.blank?
  tempdirname = "C:/thistemporary/"
  temp = Dir.mkdir( tempdirname )
  puts "tempfolder is created"
  haus.each do |file|
    dataname = File.join( tempdirname, file.name )
    datavalue = file.data
    File.open( dataname, 'w' ){ |f| f << datavalue }
    puts "#{dataname} is created"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response. but I get confuse, why do you use File.join of temp folder with the filename. As expected, I get this error : can't convert Fixnum into String. I used temp2 = temp.to_s , and call File.join ( temp2, file.name ) but it shows No such file or directory - 0/hause_withredcolour

Comment: unfortunately, it still did not solve the problem, because now it shows         undefined method `<' for #<File:0x91aafb4>

Comment: misstyped again. use `<<` istead of `<`