# What does left shift mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Can anyone explain to me what does the "shift left" syntax in ruby means?

For instance, I have this

```
File.open( folder, 'w' ){ |f| f << datavalue }
```

I know that it means to write each datavalue to folder, but the `|f| f << datavalue` part does not make sense to me. Why does the f is inside the bracket, in relation to shift left and write the datavalue to folder?

Basically, I don"t understand the meaning of this line

```
{ |f| f << datavalue }
```

Comment: I think you should consider reading some intro to Ruby language. There are plenty of Ruby tutorials for beginners. It would help you understand answers you get on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259332/ruby-write-value-from-sql-table-to-a-tmp-folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File.open( folder, 'w' ){ |f| f << datavalue }` is the same as writing:

```
File.open( folder, 'w' ) do |f|
  f << datavalue
end
```

Both are examples of Ruby block notation. Blocks in Ruby are anonymous methods. The variables the block expects are declared between vertical bars. In this case the variable `f` represents the file object returned via the File.open command.

As regards the `<<` operator. Here it is being used as a concatenator. I believe it's called an append operator when used on objects (such as strings, arrays, in this case a file). The exception is if the object is numeric, which is when it becomes the shift left operator to shift the bits of a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_text = "world!"
hello = "Hello, "

hello << some_text

puts hello # prints "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Then answer is: It depends. I don't want to nitpick but Ruby hardly has any real operators. In Ruby most "operators" are in fact methods which is possibly as in Ruby everything is an object.

E.g. consider this code

```
o.x = a + b
```

There are no operators here because in fact this is only an alternative way for writing this code

```
o.x=(a.+(b))
```

And `x=` is the name of a setter method and `+` is also just the name of a method of the object `a`. In Ruby characters that are operators in other languages can be used as a part of method name (just think of `?` which is commonly used in Ruby method names).

So this code

```
a = b << c
```

Is in fact the same as writing

```
a = b.<<(c)
```

So what `<<` does depends on how `b` implements this method.

E.g. for a `String` the `<<` method means append.

```
a = "Hello, " << "Word"
# a == "Hello, Word"
```

But in case of a `Fixnum` the `<<` method just means shift left:

```
a = 5 << 2
# a == 20
```

So it cannot be answered what `<<` means, you have to look up in the documentation what it means for the object you are passing this method to. If you write your own class, you can just implement this operator in any way you like

```
class MyClass
  # If you prefer, can also be written as
  # def << x 
  def << ( x )
    # do something with x
  end
end

o = MyClass.new()
x = o << a
```

Your method `<<` is called and you decide what it does with `a`.